# Transitions - Can't get span to both rotate and change margin-top value

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a span rotate by 90° and to change margin-top on hover, but failing.

The span does rotate, but doesn't change its margin-top.

HTML

```
<div class="cheersWrapper">
    <span class="cheers">
        <h1>Hi!</h1>
    </span>
    <span class="smile">
        <h1>&nbsp; :)</h1>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cheersWrapper{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 5s;
    transition-duration: 5s;
}


.cheersWrapper .smile { 
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}

.cheersWrapper:hover .smile { 
    display: inline-block;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;


    transition: margin-top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top;
    -moz-transition: margin-top .5s;
    -o-transition: margin-top .5s;

}

.cheersWrapper:hover .smile:hover{

    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);

    margin-top:-25px;

}

.cheersWrapper .cheers{
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vmrq7ep7/3/

It looks like it has a sort of a Parkinson syndrome and it's stuck.

How can I make it animate its margin top?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css `translate` instead of margin for the `.cheersWrapper:hover .smile:hover` class:

```
transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0,-25px);
```

Then for the `.cheersWrapper:hover .smile` class set:

```
transition-property: transform;
```

Edited jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vmrq7ep7/4/

btw you should only need the `-webkit-` prefix and `-ms-` for IE9.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks a lot man, didn't know I could use translate to do it. +1!